# Heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation in simple linear regression?

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity

While looking through a simple linear regression, I noted the presence of both heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation, and am looking to understand the consequences of each. On this project, I am not in a position to take corrective steps to improve the regression, only to analyze results and comment on possible effects of these two conditions.

I'm writing a quick summary to include in a non-technical report, and the only metrics we use from this regression are the **slope of the regression line, the r-squared value, and the F-statistic**.

My question to this group is: **In simple linear regression, what are the effects of heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation these three measures?** Using R for some quick simulation, it seems that r-squared is not impacted by either heteroskedasticity or autocorrelation, though I'd prefer to have a slightly more rigorous explanation if possible.

Comment: To understand what "impacted" really means, it would help to have a model or scenario in which neither autocorrelation nor heteroscedasticity are present (to serve as a reference).  The answer actually depends profoundly on this reference situation. For instance, high positive serial correlation will induce $R^2$ values close to $1$ when the explanatory variable is not highly dispersed, but can have negligible effect when that variable has large dispersion. The answer also depends on the nature of the heteroscedasticity.

Comment: @whuber thank you for your response. This might just be my misunderstanding, but since we're dealing with simple linear regression (which I did not make explicit above, but defined as 1 independent variable and an intercept), wouldn't the r-squared be equivalent to the square of the correlation coefficient?

Comment: There are two "correlations" in play here: one is the correlation between the dependent and explanatory variables. The other is the serial correlation coefficient (or coefficients, if you consider multiple lags) of the dependent variable when sorted by the explanatory variable (often thought of as "time" or the equivalent).  The R-squared is the square of the former but has little to do with the latter, which measures the degree of the "autocorrelation" to which you refer.